# Select not changing value after jQuery load event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Within my below example, I've a little select and a button. When I change the select value to e.g., 5 and press the button to reload the HTML select, I am wondering now why the displayed value inside the select is not reset after the jQuery load event, even if I set `selected="selected"` inside my HTML code?

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
      let select = $('#select');

      console.log(`Value before: ${select.val()}`);

      $('#wrapper').load(window.location.href + " #wrapper", function() {
        let select = $('#select');

        console.log(`Value after: ${select.val()}`);
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select id="select" name="quantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button>Load</button>
```

Comment: running the script in the snippet and observing the network tab in devtools it shows the request returns 404 with the reason `CORS Missing Allow Origin` but I didn't try further than that. For example I would expect the `#` to follow immediately the url with no whitespace but I'm not sure that's a problem

Comment: inside the load call (which returns a Cors Error) you've already select the same select with ID , so it'll always return the same value ! , what want you to achieve exactely ?

Comment: @BourbiaBrahim hm I still don't get it. I want the value to be reset to 2 after the reload in case I set it to a different value before.

Comment: Because SO blocks my .load() event, you can find my JSFiddle example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=OS6p6AV2RD 

Even if the load event works there, the result is still the selected value and not the `selected="selected"` one